# No performance bonus using multithreading with pytube

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures, pytube

I am using the pytube library to retrieve stream information for a list of YouTube videos. I have implemented the retrieval of streams using a simple loop, as well as using the concurrent.futures and multiprocessing libraries for multithreading. However, I am not seeing the performance boost I was expecting and all methods take around 130 seconds to run.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
def _get_streams(self, yt: pytube.YouTube):
    return yt.streams

@print_execution_time
def get_streams_futures(self):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_results = [executor.submit(self._get_streams, yt) for yt in self._create_yt_obj()]
        result = [future.result() for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_results)]
    return result


@print_execution_time
def get_streams_linear(self):
    return [yt.streams for yt in self._create_yt_obj()]


@print_execution_time
def get_streams_multiprocessing(self):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(self._get_streams, self._create_yt_obj())

    return result
```

`@print_execution_time` is a simple decorator to calculate the run time of the function

I expected the multithreading methods to run much faster than the loop method, but this is not the case. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what can be done to achieve the desired performance boost?

There are no errors being raised

Comment: May need to adjust the number of threads that you use. https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-number-of-threads/

Comment: Adjusting the number of threads didn't work